# Enhance query runtime besides limit

Tags: sql

I have a SQL to select items from 2 tables (massive database). I try to speed up the process by using a LIMIT at each table. However, the result is not significant. Is there any other ways I can improve the query time further?

Original Query

```
select a.item_id,
    from
        (SELECT distinct item_id
         FROM dim_item) a

        INNER JOIN

        (SELECT item_id
         FROM dim_item_attr) b

    on a.item_id = b.item_id
```

Added Limit 10

```
select a.item_id,
    from
        (SELECT distinct item_id
         FROM dim_item
         LIMIT 10) a

        INNER JOIN

        (SELECT item_id
         FROM dim_item_attr
         LIMIT 10) b

    on a.item_id = b.item_id
    limit 10
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Your query is not clear, what are you trying to retrieve? which dbms engine you are using? are there indexes present on those columns for those 2 tables - need more details to give you better guidance.

Comment: As long as you have distinct clauses the rdbms must complete the query execution and it can apply the limit only after that.

Comment: Maybe the exact limit number is not critical, you can remove the distinct keywords, remove the subqueries and perform a simple join, limiting to some bigger number like 1000 hoping that there would be 10 distinct values in there then run another query on top of it with distinct and limit 10.

Comment: Please include the table definition and their keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any details on tables, keys, indexes, DBMS etc it is kind of hard to give any suggestions, but I would start with simplifying the query:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM dim_item a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dim_item_attr b
    WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id
);
```